# How to generate incremental identifier in java

Tags: java

I have requirement in which I continuously receive messages that needs to be written in a file. Every time a new message is received it needs to be written in a separate file. What I want is to generate an unique identifier to be used as a file-name. I also want to preserve the order of the messages as well. By this I mean, the identifier generated as a file-name should always be incremental.

I was using **UUID.randomUUID()** to generate file-names but the problem with this approach is that UUID only assures randomness of the identifier but is not incremental. As a result I am losing the ordering of the file (I want file generated first should appear first in the list).

Approaches known

1. Can use System.currentTimeMillis() but I can receive multiple messages at same time stamp.

2.Another approach could be to implement static long value and increment it whenever a file is to be created and use the long value as a file-name. But I am not sure about this approach. Also it doesn't seem to be a proper solution to my problem. I think there could be far better solutions than this one.

If someone could suggest me a better solution to this problem, will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd just add one each time to a BigInteger with a higher base than 10

Comment: can-t you prepend the timestamp to the uuid? so you both preserve order (the timestamp) and have randomness in the ids

Comment: @AJcodez : Can you please explain the above approach with an example. It can help me to understand in a better way.

Comment: @ph. : What you are saying seems good enough. But my only concern is the ids will be too long if you prepend timestamp to it.

Comment: @Ankur I'm not sure it is really an issue to have a file name of 50 char

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your id value to uniformly rise even between server restarts, then you must either base it on the system time or have some elaborately robust logic that persists the last ID used. Note that achieving robustness on its own is not hard, but achieving it in a performant and scalable way is.

If you additionally need the id to be unique across multiple nodes in a redundant server cluster, then you need even more elaborate logic, which definitely involves a persistent store to which all the boxes synchronize access. Making this performant is, of course, even harder.

The best option I can see is to have a quite long ID so there's room for these parts:

1. `System.currentTimeMillis` for long-term uniqueness (across restarts);
2. `System.nanotime` for finer granularity;
3. a unique id of each server node (determined in a platform-specific way).

The method will still have to remember the last value generated and retry in case of a duplicate. It won't have to retry too many times, though, just until the next `nanoTime` clock tick—it could even busy-wait for it.

Sketch of code without point 3 (single-node implementation):

```
private static long lastNanos;
public static synchronized String uniqueId() {
  for (;/*ever*/;) {
    final long n = System.nanoTime();
    if (n == lastNanos) continue;
    lastNanos = n;
    return "" + System.currentTimeMillis() + n;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've deleted my admittedly flaky answer and up voted yours. Please try to not be so agressive in your future comments to others.

Comment: @AdrianRegan Sorry about that, I didn't notice the aggressive tone (sometimes it slips, I guess). It is easy to confuse direct tone with aggressiveness. For the record, I didn't downvote your solution :)

Comment: No problem. But you would have been right to. I need coffee... :-)

Comment: Ohh I thought it was for me .. anyways chill guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my hands up. My last answer was fairly flaky and I've deleted it.

Keeping with the spirit of the site, I thought I'd try a different tac.

If you say you are keeping these messages in a single file then you could try something like creating an unique Id out of the size of the file?

Before you write the message to the file it's id could be the current size of the file.

You could add the filename + size as the id if these messages need to be unique across a number of files.

I'll leave the **hot potato** of synchronization to another day. But you could wrap all of this up in a syncronized object that keeps track of things.

Also, I am assuming that any messages written to the file will not be removed in the future.

ADDITIONAL NOTE:
You could create an message processing object that opens the file on construction (or via a create method).
This object will get the initial size of the file and this will be used as the unique id.
As each message is added (in a synchronized manner), the id is incremented by the size of the message.
This would address the performance issues. Will not work if more than one JVM/Node accesses the same file.

Skeletal Idea:

```
public class MessageSink {
    private long id = 0;

    public MessageSink(String filename) {
       id = ... get file size ..
    }

    public synchronized addMessage(Message msg) {
       msg.setId(id);
       .. write to file + flush ..
       .. or add to stack of messages that need to be written to file
       .. at a later stage.
       id = id + msg.getSize();
    }

    public void flushMessages() {
       .. open file
       .. for each message in stack write ...
       .. flush and close file
    }
}
```

Comment: This could work (and a quite clever idea!), but the problem I see is that the file will have to be kept open all the time and there could be platform-specific trouble with determining the size of a file currently open for writing. Constantly opening and closing the file would fix that, but could result in bad performance.

Comment: I will always keep a fixed number of messages in a single file. Moreover the messages can also be of the same length with slight minor changes if any. These messages stored are not permanent. I will wipe out the files once I have processed them.

Comment: I think it would have to happen in a 'tranactional' context, i.e. open, get size, write, close, flush. It'll be slow but since @Ankur is already writing to a file it could be incorporated into this functionality. I have no idea how many messages arrive or the rate. But if it's slow and not time critical ??

Comment: @AdrianRegan :  Message can arrive at arbitrary rate. I can also have a case where bunch of messages arrive at same instance or in a very short duration say few milliseconds or so.

Comment: @Ankur then you can queue them up in the MessageSink class to be flushed to file later. The rolling id is simply current id + size of message. If you get the synchronization right then it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement and found a suitable solution. Twitter Snowflake uses a simple algorithm to generate **sortable 64bit (long) ids**. Snowflake is written on Scala but the approach is simple and could be easily used in a Java code.

id is composed of:
*timestamp* - 41 bits (millisecond precision w/ a custom epoch gives us 69 years);
*machine id* - 10 bits (MAC address could be used as a hardware id);
*sequence number* - 12 bits - rolls over every 4096 per machine (with protection to avoid rollover in the same ms)

Formula looks like: `((timestamp - customEpoch) << timestampShift) | (machineId << machineIdShift) | sequenceNumber;`

Shift for each component depends on it's bits position in ID.

Detailed description and source code could be found at github:

[Twitter Snowflake](https://github.com/twitter/snowflake)

[Basic Java implementation of the Snowflake algorithm](https://github.com/Predictor/javasnowflake/)