# Generate auto increment number by using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to generate unique auto increment id which will started from `0`.
I found something for doing this using below code:

```
private static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);   
uniqueID = count.incrementAndGet();
```

I can create auto increment ID by manually :

For example :

```
int i = 0; // Obviously I will declare this variable as global
++i;
```

In this way I can manage to do this. But I don't want to do this manually. I am finding some java method which will take of all this stuff.

And I found below code :

```
private static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);   
uniqueID = count.incrementAndGet();
```

Now my question is, Is this the right way to generate unique ID? Or, is there any other better solution?

Comment: This will only work in a single-process environment.

Comment: This will be only unique within a single JVM run.  Starts from 0 again when you restart your program. Will not be unique across different machines.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911163/how-to-generate-incremental-identifier-in-java?rq=1

Comment: What are the requirements? How is the ID to be used? Will it be shared/persisted? Is it a problem that it's guessable?

Comment: Without more requirements, it's unclear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Thilo This ID will be used as shared.

Comment: So you don't need `int`/`long` but `UUID`

Answer (score 0):

If it should be unique only within a single process, then yes you can use an AtomicInteger.

Comment: Would request you to add some more details.