# Generate auto increment id in java

Tags: java

I have already asked this before how to generate auto increment ID [Generate auto increment number by using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35078825/generate-auto-increment-number-by-using-java).

I have used below code:

```
private static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);   
uniqueID = count.incrementAndGet();
```

The previous code working fine but the problem is `count` static variable. For this static its never start to `0` again, its always start with the last increment id. That is the issue.

Is there any alternative way except `AtomicInteger`?

Another issue is that I am working on GWT so `AtomicInteger` is not available in GWT.

So I have to find another way to do that.

Comment: `its never start to 0 again, its always start with the last increment id` - isn't that the subject of an auto-increment? Or are you asking how you can restart at `0`?

Comment: I am asking about how to reset it to 0 again.

Comment: Did you try `count.set(0)`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#set-int-

Comment: How do you know that this time it is supposed to be 0 and not incrememented by 1?

Comment: When do you want to reset it back to 0?

Comment: Why? You should be doing this sort of thing with a database.

Comment: @EJP I want to do this programmatically . Another thing is that I am not using any database.

Comment: You want a **uniqueId**. So why do you want to restart from 0? Then, if you do the id is not **unique** anymore!

Answer (score 1):

`AtomicInteger` is a "signed" integer. It will increase till `Integer.MAX_VALUE`; then, due to integer overflow, you expect to get `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Unfortunately, most of the thread safe methods in `AtomicInteger` are final, including `incrementAndGet()`, so you cannot override them.

But you could create a custom class that wraps an AtomicInteger and you just create `synchronized` methods according to your needs. For instance:

```
public class PositiveAtomicInteger {

    private AtomicInteger value;

    //plz add additional checks if you always want to start from value>=0
    public PositiveAtomicInteger(int value) {
        this.value = new AtomicInteger(value);
    }

    public synchronized int incrementAndGet() {
        int result = value.incrementAndGet();
        //in case of integer overflow
        if (result < 0) {
            value.set(0);
            return 0;
        }
        return result;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);    
count.set(0);    
uniqueID = count.incrementAndGet();
```

Comment: I don't know if you saw OP's edit: *"Is there any alternative way except `AtomicInteger`?"* Also, code only answers with no explanations are usually frowned upon.